# How can I define global variables in nunjucks?

Tags: node.js, nunjucks

Using [nunjucks](http://jlongster.github.io/nunjucks/), how can I define some global variables that should always be available within all templates?

Ideally, they would be specified somewhere in the environment or config options and not have to be merged into the context dict with each call to `nunjucksEnvironment.render`.

Comment: If you happen to be using Express, you can use [`app.locals`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.locals) to store global variables.

Comment: @robertklep: No Express, just Connect.

Comment: Actually, I want to use these templates client-side too, so... the solution can't have a dependency on server-side tech.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was just looking for this and came here. Looks like there's now a recommended way which was added in recently in [version 1.0.6](https://github.com/mozilla/nunjucks/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#v106-august-15-2014).

See [Environment.addGlobal](http://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/api.html#addglobal).

Answer (score 10):

It might be also helpfull for someone. It is possible to avoid writing any js code when dealing with global variables in [nunjucks](http://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/).

You need to create a **_globals.html** file, which contains all the global variables.

```
{% set some_var1 = "Foo" %}
{% set some_var2 = "Bar" %}
```

Then include **_globals.html** to any page, where you need the global variable. E.g. **somePage.html**

```
{% import '_globals.html' as globals %}

<span>{{globals.some_var1 }}</span>
<span>{{globals.some_var2 }}</span>
```

For more info please check http://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html#set

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  No need to rebuild your js, or gulpfile with this approach, unless your global data "needs" to be JavaScript based.

Answer (score 5):

It's not documented (or perhaps advised), but this works:

```
var njglobals = require('nunjucks/src/globals');
njglobals.someVar = 'someValue';
```

You can now use `someVar` in your templates.

Be sure not to overwrite any of the existing properties of the `njglobals` object, though (for `nunjucks@1.0.1`, they are `range`, `cycler` and `joiner`).

Comment: Not sure why globals aren't advised. I want to set a "debug" environment variable, for example, to conditionally include livereload and minified files.

Comment: It's not so much not advised, it's re-using an internal part of the module because there doesn't seem to be a public API for it :)