# How do access NODE_ENV in Nunjucks template?

Tags: node.js, express, templates, nunjucks

I have some Nunjucks template blocks that I want to render only in certain environments. I can't seem to access the `NODE_ENV` variable though. I tried this:

```
{% if process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' %}
  <div>rendering some stuff here</div>
{% endif %}
```

This didn't seem to work for me though. It didn't seem to have any idea what `process.env.NODE_ENV` was.

Is it possible to access an environment variable like this in a template?

Comment: Where is your environment variable set and how? Maybe in your case it could be undefined, then you should set it to an default value. take a look at this: https://github.com/JohnnyDevNull/express-api-typescript-template/blob/master/src/server.ts and this: https://github.com/JohnnyDevNull/express-api-typescript-template/blob/master/package.json where i set my env variables

Comment: It's set in my app.js.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up doing the following in my `app.js`

```
nunjucks.configure('views', {
  ...
}).addGlobal('NODE_ENV', process.env.NODE_ENV)
```

This simply adds `NODE_ENV` as a globally accessible variable in my Nunjucks template.

Answer (score 2):

You can use one of these variants:

1. Use `addGlobal` to define function which returns environment

   ```
   var nunjucks  = require('nunjucks');
   var env = nunjucks.configure();

   env.addGlobal('$environment', () => process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development');
   var res = nunjucks.renderString(`{{$environment()}}`);

   console.log(res);
   ```
2. Define `$environment` as [global](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20822726/how-can-i-define-global-variables-in-nunjucks).
3. Set `res.locals.environment` in middleware

   ```
   const app = express();

   app.use(function (req, res, next) {
       res.locals.$environment = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
       next();
   });

   // In nunjucks template
   {{$environment}}
   ```